# Is it possible to calculate variance on stochastic variable using multiple formulas?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

Trying to calculate what the variance is when throwing two dice simultaneously. To calculate the variance i use the formula

$$\frac 1 n \sum_{i = 1}^n(x_i - \overline{x})^2 = \frac 1 n \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 $$

Yet, I'm also aware of the other way to do the calculation:
$$\operatorname{Var}(X) = \sigma^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n P(X=x_i)\cdot (x_i - \mu)^2$$

But when i plot the numbers in to the formula i dont get the same answer.

[Here i  have included my worksheet made in excel to show how i calculated it all. I tried to make everything as organised as possible.[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilJEn.png)

Now here my variance following the first formula will total $110$, and i should therefore divide i by $36$ to get my final answer. This yields $3,05$ which is not the correct answer. In my workbook from school they have included the original formula with the answers, and for the total variance they get $210$ instead of $110$. What am i doing wrong?

Here are pictures of my workbook. With the formula that yields the right answer.  [With the formula that yields the right answer.[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exyoJ.jpg)
[And the one i used.[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziwwe.png)

Comment: You are calculating the variance of the sum, aren't you?

Comment: @zoli The variance of the sum? Yes, i belive so. Because i first take every x value and subtract it from the excepted value. Then i square it, and add it all up. The sum here equals 110, (not 210 as is written on my book) and i then divide that number by 36 (the number of observations)

Comment: Huh, how is that right? I am supposed to take the $x_i - \mu$ and sum it up for all the $x$ values.

Comment: No, no, ignore my silly comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your total of $110$ assumes each of the numbers $2$ through $12$ occurs only once in your list. But this list is this:
$$
2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,12
$$
I.e. $x_1=2,$ $x_2=3,$ $x_3=3,$ and so on.

So the sum is $210$, and $\dfrac{210}{36} = 5.833333\ldots\,.$

Comment: Oh, i see. So i am supposed to think about it in terms of every independent value, and not the values the random variable $X$ can take? Or how would i go about it?

Comment: @Anon : The expression $\displaystyle \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2$ is used only when terms of that some come from outcomes that are equally probable, so their probability is $1/n$. In this case $2$ and $3$ are not equally probable, but all $36$ outcomes of the throw of two dice are equally probable. Because all $36$ are equally probable, we can use that expression with $n=36. \qquad$

Comment: A couple of other issues arise: $(1)$ Often $\mu$ is the mean of population from which $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ make up a random sample. In that case $\bar x = (x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$ is the mean of the sample and generally would differ from $\mu,$ the mean of the whole population. $(2)$ Often the number reported as the value of the "sample variance" is $\displaystyle \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2.$ That should be done, if at all, ONLY when $\bar x$ is the mean of a random sample that may differ from the population mean $\mu.$ The purpose of changing $n$ to $n-1 \text{ in}\,\ldots \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$that case is to compensate for the fact that using $\bar x$ instead of $\mu$ makes the sum smaller. $\qquad$